# indentation issue python in sign detection script

Tags: python

I have a script with I try to detect STOP sign in the traffic, but I have a problem with indentation, and I don't know how to solve it...

Image with the code:
[image]

And error message:

[image]

Comment: What is unclear about the error?

Comment: I'm gonna take a stab. This is Spyder and you've played around with some settings. Are you using Spyder?

Comment: how can I solve it?

Comment: *I have a picture of a script...

Comment: "are you using Spyder?" -- > "how can I solve it?". Nice to know we're having a constructive dialogue where you answer the other person's questions.

Comment: Yes.` I'm using spyder, and I set the indentation to 4 spaces

Comment: This is actually practically the only instance where code-as-image is a good thing; it would be unsolvable if pasting code had folded tabs into spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clearly see (even if code-in-image is a no-no) line 24 has spaces, line 25 has tabs.

Make them all spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix tab and space for indentation. Make all of them either space or tab.